# Comparing two dataframes in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I'm comparing two dataframes in spark using `except()`.

For exmaple: `df.except(df2)`

I will get all the records that are not available in `df2` from `df`. However, I would like to list field details also which are not matching.

For example:

```
df:
------------------
id,name,age,city
101,kp,28,CHN
------------------

df2:
-----------------
id,name,age,city
101,kp,28,HYD
----------------
```

Expected output:

```
df3
--------------------------
id,name,age,city,diff
101,kp,28,CHN,City is not matching
--------------------------------
```

How can I acheive this?

Comment: To help people understand what you are trying to do, you could provide a sample input, and your expected output. For instance, what would you expect with `val df1 = sc.parallelize(Seq(1,2,3,4,5)).toDF("A")` and `val df2 = sc.parallelize(Seq(6,9,3,4,5)).toDF("A")`? By the way, if you're new to stackoverflow, I recommend that you read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. It will help you write better questions and thus have better answers ;)

Comment: Unclear if positional dependencies meant or not

Comment: I no longer see df2 in the example, I think you need to clarify

Comment: What you want in the `diff` column seems only possible when there is a single row in both dataframes. What do you expcet to happen if both are larger?

Comment: Question is indeed ambiguous in more than one way

Comment: @KPM Here is the solution - I think

Comment: Can you remove all your conversational comments here above now? they are just noise now

Comment: Would a DatasetComparison module from https://github.com/AbsaOSS/hermes help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newer again attempt on the above but not possible elegantly, but with JOIN as opposed to except. Best I can do.

I believe it does what you need and takes into the fact there are things in one data set or not.

Run under Databricks.

```
case class Person(personid: Int, personname: String, cityid: Int)
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df1 = Seq(
     Person(0, "AgataZ", 0),
     Person(1, "Iweta", 0),
     Person(2, "Patryk", 2),
     Person(9999, "Maria", 2),
     Person(5, "John", 2),
     Person(6, "Patsy", 2),
     Person(7, "Gloria", 222), 
     Person(3333, "Maksym", 0)).toDF

val df2 = Seq(
     Person(0, "Agata", 0),
     Person(1, "Iweta", 0),
     Person(2, "Patryk", 2),
     Person(5, "John", 2),
     Person(6, "Patsy", 333),
     Person(7, "Gloria", 2), 
     Person(4444, "Hans", 3)).toDF

val joined = df1.join(df2, df1("personid") === df2("personid"), "outer") 
val newNames = Seq("personId1", "personName1", "personCity1", "personId2", "personName2", "personCity2")
val df_Renamed = joined.toDF(newNames: _*)

// Some deliberate variation shown in approach for learning 
val df_temp = df_Renamed.filter($"personCity1" =!= $"personCity2" || $"personName1" =!= $"personName2" || $"personName1".isNull || $"personName2".isNull || $"personCity1".isNull || $"personCity2".isNull).select($"personId1", $"personName1".alias("Name"), $"personCity1", $"personId2", $"personName2".alias("Name2"), $"personCity2").  withColumn("PersonID", when($"personId1".isNotNull, $"personId1").otherwise($"personId2"))

val df_final = df_temp.withColumn("nameChange ?", when($"Name".isNull or $"Name2".isNull or $"Name" =!= $"Name2", "Yes").otherwise("No")).withColumn("cityChange ?", when($"personCity1".isNull or $"personCity2".isNull or $"personCity1" =!= $"personCity2", "Yes").otherwise("No")).drop("PersonId1").drop("PersonId2")

df_final.show()
```

gives:

```
+------+-----------+------+-----------+--------+------------+------------+
|  Name|personCity1| Name2|personCity2|PersonID|nameChange ?|cityChange ?|
+------+-----------+------+-----------+--------+------------+------------+
| Patsy|          2| Patsy|        333|       6|          No|         Yes|
|Maksym|          0|  null|       null|    3333|         Yes|         Yes|
|  null|       null|  Hans|          3|    4444|         Yes|         Yes|
|Gloria|        222|Gloria|          2|       7|          No|         Yes|
| Maria|          2|  null|       null|    9999|         Yes|         Yes|
|AgataZ|          0| Agata|          0|       0|         Yes|          No|
+------+-----------+------+-----------+--------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: Yes it is not easy to implement, that is where I got stuck.

Comment: But what do u exactly want? N cols. Two sides to the data

Comment: Along with differences, column name details also to be displayed.

Comment: df3
--------------------------
id,name,age,city,diff
101,kp,28,CHN,City is not matching
--------------------------------

Comment: I am going to send you an answer soon, that will have to do. I am on holidays and like teasing myself with these questions, but this is the final effort

Comment: Have a look, interesting issue for sure.

Comment: Great effort thanks for doing it. since I'm using 1.6 may be the reason for below error: can not resolve '(personcity2 || personname1)' due to data type mismatch. differing types (int and string).  this error at defining dataframe def_temp

Comment: okay, I will try that and test. I'm trying to do that in a dynamic way. right now I'm supplying sql queries as two parameters to my script..  need to make it generalized. This will be best solution for others as well. thanks again.

Comment: Cheers. Try Databricks

Comment: Could you please check once, what filter is doing exactly here. There was no difference between df_Renamed and df_temp.

Comment: that might be true in some cases, but mine did have a difference. or for renaming columns

Comment: Hi..Other than full outer join , any other way? mostly I wanted it to be generalized. and number of columns will be around 40+

Comment: It was about the principle that except is not the way to go and there are 2 sides to it - which was not reflected in your post. writing a generator for the cols etc. is a different question, you need to take the basics and then apply specifically. the basis are the clue, the rest is add to specifically. success - I could not find another way, but may be there is

Comment: As a final comment: we wrote a Scala program that could read csv files and load to HDFS. It was pluggable in that it could be parameterized for simple csv relational like formats. I think that is somewhere along the lines of what you need to do and generate the statements somewhere and then presto execute those outputted statements.

Answer (score 3):

Use intersect to get the values common to both DataFrames,then build your not matching logic

intersect -returns a new Dataset containing rows only in both this Dataset and another Dataset.

```
df.intersect(df2)
```

- return a new RDD that contains the intersection of elements in the source dataset and the argument.
- intersection(anotherrdd) returns the elements which are present in both the DF.
- intersection(anotherrdd) remove all the duplicate including duplicated in single DF

Comment: Intersect returns only unique values between two dfs!